# Configuring Hive to run in Local Mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Hi I am trying to run Hive in local mode, I have set the HIVE_OPTS environment variable

```
export HIVE_OPTS='-hiveconf 
mapred.job.tracker=local 
-hiveconf fs.default.name=file:////<myhomedir>/hivelocal/tmp 
-hiveconf hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:////<myhomedir>/hivelocal/warehouse
-hiveconf javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/<myhomedir>/hivelocal/metastore_db;create=true'
```

and connected to hive using `hive` client

when I create the table(name `demo`), I still see the table is getting created in the `default` database in HDFS. I was expecting the table to be created in the local file system(`file:///`) as I have the set the warehouse using `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:////<myhomedir>/hivelocal/warehouse`

Am I missing something here?

PS : I am using Cloudera distribution

Answer (score 3):

I too was facing the same problem. Below are the steps (with trial & error), I had followed to fix the same.

1. go to **`/etc/hive/conf`** & rename **`hive-site.xml`** generated by cloudera.
2. check the permission for the **`/tmp/hive`** and give appropriate permission.For the time being, just to test, I had given:

   `[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo chmod 777 /tmp/hive/`
3. Configure local mode:

   `[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ export HIVE_OPTS='-hiveconf mapred.job.tracker=local -hiveconf fs.default.name=file:///home/cloudera/hivelocal/tmp -hiveconf hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=file:///home/cloudera/hivelocal/warehouse –hiveconf  javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/cloudera/hivelocal/metastore_db;create=true'`
4. Create table:

   `hive>  Create table doc_one(text string) row format delimited fields  terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;`
5. Table is created successfully in **`/home/cloudera/hivelocal/`**

Comment: Thanks @Vinkal. but, It is not possible for me to rename the `hive-site.xml` as I am working in a common dev box.