# Hive cli can not be run from brew installed hive

Tags: macos, hive

The brew installed hive appears to be a bit shy on maturity. First I had to **manually** edit the derby initailization script:

[Unable to initialize hive with Derby from Brew install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947930/unable-to-initialize-hive-with-derby-from-brew-install)

Having done so .. when starting the `cli` it just hangs:

```
 $hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
```

So having now run into two serious issues .. and not yet having seen `hive` actually work ..  is there a  known workaround or better alternative for `brew [re]install hive` ?

Update: I found another Q&A that solved the second portion of my question.

> Configuring Hive to run in Local Mode

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312359/1056563

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase the log level to see what is going on. The logging configuration seems to be inside a jar file but based on the [source in git](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/main/resources/hive-log4j2.properties) you can change the root logger level with system property `hive.log.level`. The default is INFO, so try running with `-Dhive.log.level=DEBUG` or even `TRACE`.

You can probably ignore the warning about multiple SLF4J bindings, but in case this worries you, the Log4j2 [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#exclusions) explains how to exclude the dependency on the old log4j slf4j binding.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The OP was actually about the `cli` *hanging* .

Comment: @javadba Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer to be more relevant.